# Cent OS 6 restarts immediately after booting

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I have a server with CentOs 6 which restarts in loop.

It loads all modules correctly, then login prompt appears and then it immediately starts umount ing drives and goes to restart.

Does anyone knows how to stop it from restarting? `CTRL`+`C`  doesn't help.
Or maybe i should alter boot modules somehow?

I am thinking about booting from some live cd, but i'm not sure where to look to disable restart in the end.

Answer (score 2):

CentOS 6 by default also provides an alternative "safe mode" in the Grub bootloader menu, which should take you into a single user shell. If the system stays up in that mode, you can at least take a look at the logs to get an idea of what's causing the reboots in "normal mode".

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot from a Live CD or even from the console into single user mode then that's probably the way to go.

Once you have access to the system you will have to roll up you sysadmin sleeves and get stuck in to your logs. You should check your boot.log, messages etc and any other log files that are present for any relevant information.

The rest depends upon what you find in your logs. I find google  (other search engines are available) a valuable resource at this pint.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it, but wanted to try to boot from local disk first. CentOs single mode

Comment: Then use the option to boot into safe mode when it is presented during system boot.